# Actionscript 3 redrawing line on mouse move performance

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm refreshing my AS3 basic knowledge. Now I'm playing with creating movieclips with dimensions specified by mouse distance.

This is my full code:

http://pastebin.com/4jpqFn7N

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import wck.World;

    public class Game extends World {
        private var isDragging:Boolean = false;
        private var line:Shape = new Shape();
        private var lineInfo:Array = [];
        public function Game() {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, recalcDrag);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
        }

        private function addIt(dist:Number):void {
            var i:Rect = new Rect();
            i.x = mouseX;
            i.y = mouseY;
            i.width = dist;
            i.height = dist;

            addChild(i);
        }

        private function startDragging(e:MouseEvent):void {
            if(!(e.target is Rect)) {
                isDragging = true;
                lineInfo['bX'] = mouseX;
                lineInfo['bY'] = mouseY;
                line.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY); 
                addChild(line);
            }
        }

        private function recalcDrag(e:MouseEvent):void {
            if(isDragging) {                
                line.graphics.clear();
                line.graphics.lineStyle(10, 0x000, .65);
                line.graphics.moveTo(lineInfo['bX'], lineInfo['bY']); 
                line.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
            }
        }

        private function stopDragging(e:MouseEvent):void {
            if(isDragging) {
                var distance = DistanceTwoPoints(mouseX, lineInfo['bX'], mouseY, lineInfo['bY']);
                line.graphics.clear();
                isDragging = false;
                if(!(e.target is Rect) && distance != 0 ) addIt(distance);
            }
        }

        public function DistanceTwoPoints(x1:Number, x2:Number,  y1:Number, y2:Number): Number {
            var dx:Number = x1-x2;
            var dy:Number = y1-y2;
            return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        }
    }

}
```

However I have feeling that redrawing whole line on mouse move might be resource expensive. How can I lighten it up a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could employ an `ENTER_FRAME` event instead of a `MOUSE_MOVE` event.  `MOUSE_MOVE` is quite an expensive call, especially on mobile devices, and it has no real benefits over `ENTER_FRAME` if you set it up correctly.

also, if you're not using the timeline in *Flash Professional*, you should use `Sprite` objects instead of `MovieClip` objects.

note:  [the following code](http://pastebin.com/8YuHhFkE) is untested:

```
package
{   
    //Imports
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import wck.World;

    //Class
    public class Game extends World
    {
        //Properties
        private var line:Shape;
        private var lineInfo:Array;

        //Constructor
        public function Game()
        {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownEventListener);
        }

        //Mouse Down Event Listener
        private function mouseDownEventListener(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (!(e.target is Rect))
            {
                removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownEventListener);
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveEventListener);

                lineInfo = new Array();
                lineInfo['bX'] = mouseX;
                lineInfo['bY'] = mouseY;

                line = new Shape();
                line.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);

                addChild(line);
            }
        }

        //Mouse Move Event Listener
        private function mouseMoveEventListener(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveEventListener); 
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEventListener);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpEventListener);
        }

        //Enter Frame Event Listener
        private function enterFrameEventListener(e:Event):void
        {
            line.graphics.clear();
            line.graphics.lineStyle(10, 0x000, .65);
            line.graphics.moveTo(lineInfo['bX'], lineInfo['bY']); 
            line.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        }

        //Mouse Up Event Listener
        private function mouseUpEventListener(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEventListener);
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpEventListener);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownEventListener);

            line.graphics.clear();

            var distance:Number = distanceBetweenTwoPoints(mouseX, lineInfo['bX'], mouseY, lineInfo['bY']);

            if (!(e.target is Rect) && distance != 0)
            {
                addRectangle(distance);
            }
        }

        //Distance Between Two Points
        public function distanceBetweenTwoPoints(x1:Number, x2:Number, y1:Number, y2:Number):Number
        {
            var dx:Number = x1 - x2;
            var dy:Number = y1 - y2;

            return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        }

        //Add Rectangle
        private function addRectangle(distance:Number):void
        {
            var rect:Rect = new Rect();
            rect.x = mouseX;
            rect.y = mouseY;
            rect.width = distance;
            rect.height = distance;

            addChild(rect);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There was only one error because of checking distance value before setting it, and I've also got rid of mouse move listener at all in favor of enter frame. Thanks for explanation

Comment: you should use the `MOUSE_MOVE` event listener as a vehicle to start the `ENTER_FRAME` event, otherwise the `ENTER_FRAME` event will always be running, regardless if it's needed, which would be even more resource intensive than simply using only a `MOUSE_MOVE` event.

Answer (score 1):

Since `MOUSE_MOVE` can be fired multiple times per frame and the screen is redrawn only once per frame, there can be some unnecessary calculations. The performance might improve when using `ENTER_FRAME` event instead.